# Why is my shell variable concatenation not working on ubuntu bash?

Tags: shell

I am unable to explain the below behavior. Any ideas ?

```
    Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

     * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
    New release '14.04.2 LTS' available.
    Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

    Last login: Wed Oct 21 22:43:19 2015 from 10.0.2.2
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $0
    -bash
    vagrant@master:~$ export A=/hello
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A
    /hello
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin
    /hello/bin
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin/asd
    /hello/bin/asd
    vagrant@master:~$ export A=/hello-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A
    /hello-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin
    /hello-2.6.1/bin
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin/asd
    /hello-2.6.1/bin/asd
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
    /opt/hadoop-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME/bin
    /bin/hadoop-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME/bin1234
    /bin1234oop-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ uname -a
    Linux master 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    vagrant@master:~$ export A=/opt/hadoop-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin
    /opt/hadoop-2.6.1/bin
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A/bin/asd
    /opt/hadoop-2.6.1/bin/asd
    vagrant@master:~$ echo $A
    /opt/hadoop-2.6.1
    vagrant@master:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `HADOOP_HOME` variable has been defined to a value
that ends with a carriage return, i.e.,

> `/` `o` `p` `t` `/` `h` `a` `d` `o` `o` `p` `-` `2` `.` `6` `.` `1` <kbd>carriage return</kbd>

so when you do

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

you're getting the output

> `/` `o` `p` `t` `/` `h` `a` `d` `o` `o` `p` `-` `2` `.` `6` `.` `1` <kbd>carriage return</kbd>
>   `/` `b` `i` `n`

only all on one line, so the `/bin` *overwrites* the `/opt` on the screen
and it looks like

```
/bin/hadoop-2.6.1
```

You can check this by doing

```
A=/opt/hadoop-2.6.1
echo $A | od -cb
echo $HADOOP_HOME | od -cb
```

Try to find where `HADOOP_HOME` is being defined. 
It may be one of your "**`.`**" files;
e.g., `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.bash_profile` in your home directory,
or a similarly named file in `/etc`. 
If you use `vi`, it should show a `^M` at the end of the string;
that represents carriage return.  Delete the `^M`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the variable `$HADOOP_HOME` has a CR character at the end. Check this with `echo $HADOOP_HOME | cat -vet`. It should look like `/opt/hadoop-2.6.1$`. If so then change the file where this variable is set.